# How to download part of website with wget?

Tags: download, wget, mirror

I want to download part of this site: coinmarketcap.com

It has table of coins with pagination about 95 pages.

I want to download single page for each coin, like

coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/

On each page there are 100 links like this.

But if I use

wget https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/*

It says "no matches".

I tried to download one page with this:

wget https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Bitcoin/ -P

But the .html file is not readable hieroglyphs.

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: This question doesn't have to do with programming?

Comment: There are many similar questions about wget here. Why so rude?

Answer (score 2):

> But if I use
>
> wget https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/*
>
> It says "no matches".

You can not use `*` as wildcard when working with http (or https), it is only for FTP, from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

> File name wildcard matching(...)are available when retrieving via FTP.

> I tried to download one page with this:
>
> wget https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Bitcoin/ -P
>
> But the .html file is not readable hieroglyphs.

I tried executing your command, I got following error

```
wget: option requires an argument -- P
```

it should be `-P prefix` where prefix is path to directory where downloaded files will be stored, after I added path to existing catalog it did worked and I got `index.html` and inspected it using text editor, it starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head>
```

and does look to be correct HTML for me, though they apparently do use JavaScript a lot, so even if you download page source it might be hard to get information which you are seeing in your browser.

If your aim is to gather data it might be easier to use their API, according to [algotrading101.com](https://algotrading101.com/learn/coinmarketcap-api-guide/) part of CoinMarketCap API is free, so I suggest giving it try.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I looked at API and the thing is to get info I want with free plan I should query it each day for 30 days, so this is not my option now. And even if I buy subscription - I doubt that I can get all info. What I need is coins URL for example. This info available in data = cmc.cryptocurrency_info(symbol='BTC') but I need to query each of over 9000 coins to get it. And I have only 333 queries a day. There are also data_id_map = cmc.cryptocurrency_map() which can give info about all coins in one query, but there are no URL field, so it is useless...

Comment: Well, thank you anyway, as I figured out how to make simple python script that downloaded all I need)